# Why columns are renamed as c0,c1 in the spark partitioned data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Following is my source data,

```
 Name |Date      |
+-----+----------+
|Azure|2018-07-26|
|AWS  |2018-07-27|
|GCP  |2018-07-28|
|GCP  |2018-07-28|
```

I have partitioned the data using Date column,

```
udl_file_df_read.write.format("csv").partitionBy("Date").mode("append").save(outputPath)

val events = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema","true").load(outputPath)

events.show()
```

The output column names are `(c0,Date)`. I am not sure why the original column name is missing and how do I retain the column names?

Note This is not a duplicate question because of the below reasons Here columns other than partition columns are renamed as c0 and specifying base-path in option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retain the schema by setting the option header to true when I write my file, I earlier thought I can use this option only to read the data.

udl_file_df_read.write.option("header" ="true" ). format("csv").partitionBy("Date").mode("append").save(outputPath)

Answer (score 3):

You get column names like `c0` because CSV format as used in the question doesn't preserve column names.

You can try writing with

```
udl_file_df_read
  .write.
  .option("header", "true")
  ...
```

and similarly read

```
spark
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
```

Comment: Thanks, but my requirement is I need the output format as CSV. Is there any other way to retain the column names when we use csv as format with partitioning ?